# Issue With Adding and Deleting Function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these two functions that should add and remove the item on the list. The adding one should also calculate the total sum of all items, but it doesn't work quite exactly as it should. Here is the adding function:

```
  Future getTotal(item) async {
    int counter = 0;

    counter += int.parse(item);
    totalPrice.add(counter);

    _totalPrice.forEach((element) => counter += element);
    print(totalPrice);
    
    print(counter);
    return totalPrice;
  }
```

It first declares counter (which is sum basically), then it should onTap calculate the total sum of all items, but I get this problem, where it adds items properly, but the counter adds one extra item on the first tap, like the counter is added twice in the beginning, I suspect this code is the issue:

```
counter += int.parse(item);
totalPrice.add(counter);
```

Here is the issue in pictures:

[image]

[image]

**Now for the delete function**

I have this simple delete function, but it doesn't seem to remove any item onTap:

```
 deleteSumItem(item) {
    _totalPrice.remove(item);
    notifyListeners();
    print(totalPrice);
  }
```

It should work together with the getTotal(item) function, removing the particular item from it, but as I mentioned, it doesn't seem to do anything, and returns full list each tap.

I hope I was clear, I never seem to figure out the simple issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the element twice here: `_totalPrice.forEach((element) => counter += element);`

with regards to removing, you are using (mainly) `totalPrice` when adding but `_totalPrice` when removing. See the difference?

Comment: Yeah, that could be an issue, but how would you solve it? I tried `_totalPrice.forEach((element) => counter + element);`, but it didn't seem to work out well. As to the regards of removing function, I get it, I used _totalPrice, my bad.

Comment: quite frankly, your whole code looks a bit weird. counter is a price, I guess, etc. With your issue, I guess you want to have something like `cart.add(counter)` and `cart.forEach((e) totalPrice += e)`.

Comment: Yeah, it is not the best solution, but I had this old codebase that is not flexible, so it has to be like that.